# I'm unable to start my React Native app using npx react-native run-android on Windows 10

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, sdk

I am trying to run a react native app I cloned using android studio. I'm trying to run npx react-native run-android but I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not write cache value to 'C:\Users\imrea\.gradle\daemon\6.2\registry.bin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more det
ails.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I have already created a local.properties file and put

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\imrea\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

I followed the link and did what it told me, but I am still getting the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Update: I'm beginning to think it is some issue with my gradle. I've read a few places that I need to resync it but the option isn't in my toolbar or file dropdown like it says in many help pages. Does anyone know where this would be located inside Android Studio?

Comment: usually permissions issues come from a misconfiguration of the environment. try to double check the guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: I ran this `npm install -g expo-cli` before running npx react-native run-android but it still didn't work.